# Copy cell to another spreadsheet based on the most recent timestamp in column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to see if there's a way to copy data from a cell based on the most recent timestamp in the A column.

Column A is where the time stamps are stored, and column B is the first information that would need to be copied in the separate sheet (Sheet2).

For example, there are already two time stamps in Column A:

6/10/2022 12:03:22 (A:2)

6/10/2022 12:34:01 (A:3)

Cell A:3 would be the most recent, therefore in a cell in the other spreadsheet (Sheet2) - it would identify that and return the value that is in B3, right next to the most recent date (A:3)

Here's the form: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6dUai5wWtaWjfw8TybYg0svdpOLsc2fTjezoXbePfw/edit?usp=sharing

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SUGGESTION

You can try using a combination of [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013) & [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) as seen on this sample below:

> `=VLOOKUP(MAX('Form Responses'!A2:A), 'Form Responses'!A2:Z, 2, false)`

Based on your question, here are your goals:

1. Identify the most recent timestamp in Column `A` on your **Form Responses** sheet.
2. Get the Column `B` cell value adjacent to the Column `A`'s most recent timestamp on the **Form Responses** sheet.
3. Return that `B` cell value on your **Sheet2** sheet .

### Demonstration

- **Form Responses** sheet
  [image]
- **Sheet2**
  [image]

### References

- [Formula for Selecting Latest Date in a Row](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/42181496/formula-for-selecting-latest-date-in-a-row?hl=en)
- [Google Sheets VLOOKUP with examples](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/vlookup-google-sheets-example/)

Comment: @ADOGG If there is anything missing, feel free to comment. I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked! I was also able to use this and edit the number to show the other cells as well, I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SORT('Form Responses'!A2:B, 1, ), 1, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: This also worked! Just needed to be able to edit it to show the other cells as well, but couldn't do that with this code, but nonetheless you did offer a solution for the exact thing I asked, thank you!